# Convert String into list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert the following string into list. However I get the variable enclosed in round brackets.

```
a = '{"0": "407-1656"}, {"4": "512-873"}'

b = [a]
```

on executing above following is the value of b

```
['{"0": "407-1656"}, {"4": "512-873"}']
```

I require the output to be

```
[{"0": "407-1656"}, {"4": "512-873"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are at least a couple of simple ways of doing this. but if you are having trouble working with square brackets, what you really need is an introductory Python tutorial.

Comment: @MadPhysicist pretty sure he is trying to remove the quotes..  i think he is trying to convert his string into a list of dictionaries

Comment: @0TTT0. I understand what he is trying to do, my issue is with the lack of any real attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have tried a couple of things and have also searched sites with specific issue but no success. tried eval command and tried coverting it to list directly.

Comment: hey @muffazel
`b = [eval(c) for c in a.split(',')]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use ast.literal_eval()

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> b = literal_eval(a)
>>> b
({'0': '407-1656'}, {'4': '512-873'})
```